# Why is my carriage return not working in my perl script?

Tags: regex, macos, bash, perl

Stepping into perl from sed I am trying to practice on a CSS file but I'm having issues and I am not finding what the issue could be from multiple searches.  In my bash script I am targeting a CSS file that has:

```
.thisclass
{   font-family: "Times New Roman";
    line-height: 1.20em;
    font-size: 1.00em;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

and my goal is:

```
.thisclass {    
    font-family: "Times New Roman";
    line-height: 1.20em;
    font-size: 1.00em;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

The perl I tried is `perl -pe 's:\r^{: {\r:g'` but it doesn't work.  If I try:

`perl -pe 's:^{:foobar:g'`

the output is:

```
.thisclass
foobar  font-family: "Times New Roman";
    line-height: 1.20em;
    font-size: 1.00em;
    margin: .25em 0;
    color: rgb(0,0,0);
}
```

If I try `perl -pe 's:\r:foobar:g'` the entire document gets modified with `foobar`

In my text editor I can do `\r^{` and in my terminal I can do `s/\n{/ {\n/g;` but I cannot get a carriage return or a new line to work in perl executed through a script with `sh foo.sh`.  I have tried using `\s` (Whitespace character equivalent to [`\t\n\r\f`]) but with no success.

So why is the carriage return not working in my perl? Is there a better way to execute what I am looking to do? If there is a better way can you explain why, please.

Comment: `^` in the middle of a match isn't matching the way you expect but you don't need it. You've just asserted (with `\r`) that you are at the start of a new line. Just remove it from the first attempt and see if that works.

Comment: Are you absolutely positive you want to use "\r" instead of "\n"?  Apple switched it's preferred line ending years ago when they switched to OS X.  As a matter of fact your displayed output looks like a classic example of "success" (?) with inserting the dreaded "\r" character and having it overwrite previous characters on the line....

Comment: I've tried both `\r` and `\n` and neither work in the script but work in the text editor.  After removing `^` still doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're reading the file line-by-line, so each line ends with the carriage return or newline -- there's nothing after it.  `\r{` doesn't appear on any single line.

You can use the [`-0777`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) switch to enable slurp mode and read the whole file as a string:

```
perl -0777 -pe 's/\R{/ {\n /g' foo.css
```

The `\R` should match any type of newline, be it `\r\n`, `\r`, or `\n`.

Comment: To read the whole file, need `-0777`, not `-00`. Fixed. (`-00` would also work here, so an alternative solution would have been to change the explanation.)

Comment: Oh, right.  The `00` argument is for *paragraph* mode and I got lucky on it working here.  Literacy failure on my part.  Thanks!